# Download CKAN Revisions

Tags: api, ckan, download

Is there anyway to download revisions of data from a CKAN database?

I have been able to retrieve a revision list, but it seems as though there is no way to download individual revisions.

- Here is the [revision list](https://hub.mph.in.gov/api/3/action/package_revision_list?id=62ddcb15-bbe8-477b-bb2e-175ee5af8629)
- Here is the [package information](https://hub.mph.in.gov/api/3/action/package_show?id=62ddcb15-bbe8-477b-bb2e-175ee5af8629)

I can even [pull individual revisions](https://hub.mph.in.gov/api/3/action/revision_show?id=00a701e0-ab10-40b0-9630-82fb06c641d1)

This is a link to the [current version](https://hub.mph.in.gov/dataset/62ddcb15-bbe8-477b-bb2e-175ee5af8629/resource/2538d7f1-391b-4733-90b3-9e95cd5f3ea6/download/covid_report_demographics.xlsx)

The ID `2538d7f1-391b-4733-90b3-9e95cd5f3ea6` is not a valid revision ID, and I am unsure where that ID comes from. Anyone happen to know how to through the CKAN API?

Comment: maaaaybe you want to ask on the ckan github issues page: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues

Comment: It isn't an issue, more of a general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `2538d7f1-391b-4733-90b3-9e95cd5f3ea6` is a resource ID, not a revision ID. In CKAN, package(dataset) contains multiple resources and each of resources contain either actual data(file) or link to the data.

Revisions reflect metadata change over time. I.e, it tracks changes in dataset fields and resource fields, but do not track changes of the uploaded file. So, you cannot download previous versions of data(file).

What you can do with revision is viewing the previous title, description, etc. of the dataset. For example CKAN <= 2.8 allows to append revision to dataset id/name and view the previous version in UI:
https://hub.mph.in.gov/dataset/covid-19-case-demographics@ca33a830-f8da-4728-a238-7daa01b5bed8

But, generally, revisions have pretty restricted capabilities and they will be replaced with improved activity stream in CKAN v2.9

Comment: Thank you Tony! So, it looks like there is no way to actually down the older datasets. That is too bad. I appreciate the response.